# Steel cleaner safe for plumbing threads

Tags: plumbing, cleaning, chemicals

The area around the fittings on this radiator was pretty dirty with residue pipe dope, not been cleaned timely. As a result, it kinda solidified and collected some additional gunk. I cleaned it mechanically with a metal brush and dental tool but would like to proceed with a last chemical cleanup step. I will be priming both the radiator interface and the sittings, and painting.

I am concerned that using something like WD-40 might be a hazard to the thread seal of the fittings. Is there something better than water (which I have done multiple times) to clean off steel pipe but that is safe for the plumbing threads? Maybe rubbing alcohol or acetone?

[image]

Comment: Be careful cleaning! Old pipe dope contained toxic lead.

Comment: Please try your camera again with proper focus. That hurts my eyes and I can't see where the dope is.